# Axios doesn't seem to send cookie with saved JWT token on axios.get call

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, axios

I am trying to build a simple login feature where users can log in using username and password.
I got my backend setup with express and node. I also tested my api-endpoints using postman and they seem to work fine. /auth/login creates a token, sets the cookie and which I can see in postman and use to call /validate which correctly validates the token.

When logging in through Login.astro I can see in the server logs, that the login was successful and the token was created.
But when I try to call the /protected page my backend always says, that the token is undefined.

This seems to be the error I get when calling axios.post(...):

```bash
username: test
password: 1234
Login successful
Error checking authentication status: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403
```

I am really confused, tried googling a thousand different things but nothing seems to work. Has anybody any idea what is wrong with my code? Am I missing something?

This is my backend **server.js**:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // Import body-parser
require('dotenv').config();
const config = process.env;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const { createUser, getUser } = require('./dbController');
// const { verifyToken } = require('./middleware');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const corsOptions = {
  //   origin: ['http://localhost:5501', 'http://127.0.0.1:5501'],
  // origin: true,
  credentials: true, // Allow credentials (cookies)
  methods: 'GET,POST', // Allowed HTTP methods
  allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type,Authorization', // Allowed headers
};

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(cookieParser(config.JWT_SECRET));

function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  console.log('inside verifyToken, cookies: ', req.cookies);
  const token = req.cookies.token;
  console.log('inside verifyToken, token: ', token);
  if (!token) {
    console.log('no token provided');
    return res
      .status(403)
      .json({ isAuthenticated: false, error: 'No token provided' });
  }

  jwt.verify(token, config.JWT_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('failed to authenticate token');
      return res.status(401).json({
        isAuthenticated: false,
        error: 'Failed to authenticate token',
      });
    }
    console.log('decoded: ', decoded);
    req.user = decoded;
    next();
  });
}

app.post('/auth/signup', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // create user
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const encryptedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    const user = await createUser(username, encryptedPassword);
    res.json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    res
      .status(500)
      .json({ error: 'An error occurred while creating the user.' });
  }
});

app.post('/auth/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // get user
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    console.log('inside login, username: ', username);
    const user = await getUser(username);
    console.log('user: ', user);
    if (!user) {
      console.log('user not found');
      res.status(401).json({ error: 'Incorrect username or password' });
      return;
    }
    // check password
    const passwordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!passwordValid) {
      console.log('password invalid');
      res.status(401).json({ error: 'Incorrect username or password' });
      return;
    }
    const token = jwt.sign({ username: user.username }, config.JWT_SECRET, {
      expiresIn: '1h',
    });

    console.log('token: ', token);

    // Set the JWT token in a cookie
    res
      .status(200)
      .cookie('token', token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        signed: true,
      })
      .redirect('http://localhost:3000/protected');
    // .json({ message: 'Login successful' });

    // Send a success response
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while logging in.' });
  }
});

app.get('/auth/validate', verifyToken, (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ isAuthenticated: true, user: req.user });
});

app.listen(config.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${config.PORT}`);
});
```

I am using Astro for my frontend and want to make a GET-call to /auth/validate when entering the /protected path.
Here is my **Login.astro**:

```js
---
import axios from 'axios';

if (Astro.request.method === 'POST') {
  try {
    const data = await Astro.request.formData();
    const username = data.get('username');
    const password = data.get('password');

    console.log('username:', username);
    console.log('password:', password);

    const loginData = {
      username: username,
      password: password,
    };

    axios
      .post('http://localhost:5050/auth/login', loginData)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log('Login successful');
          // Astro.redirect('/protected');
          // You can handle the redirect or other actions here
        } else {
          console.error('Login failed with status:', response.status);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  }
}
---

<h1>Register</h1>
<form method="POST">
  <label>
    Username:
    <input type="text" name="username" required />
  </label>
  <label>
    Password:
    <input type="password" name="password" required minlength="4" />
  </label>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

And here my **protected.astro**:

```
---
import Layout from '../layouts/Layout.astro';
// import Card from '../components/Card.astro';
import Login from '../components/Login.astro';
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

axios
  .get('http://localhost:5050/auth/validate')
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data.isAuthenticated);
    if (response.data.isAuthenticated) {
      // window.location.href = '/dashboard';
    } else {
      Astro.redirect('/');
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error checking authentication status:', error);
  });
---

<Layout title="Welcome to Astro.">
  <main>
    <p>You are logged in!</p>
  </main>
</Layout>

<style></style>
```

Comment: I currently changed `secure` to `false` so that the cookie would be send with http but the same error still occurrs.